# Ansible+Gitlab, передать переменную

Tags: развертывание, ansible, gitlab-ci

Как реализовать передачу гитлабом переменной ансиблу. А точнее, как отдавать бранч в переменной? Есть гитлаб, у которого есть переменная CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME. Есть простой плейбук, который git checkout делает. Если в нем задать version, то все работает, а если в gitlab-ci.yml написать **-e version="$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"**, он это просто игнорит и деплоит из мастера

Comment: Посмотреть бы на таску `git`...

Comment: Все до омерзения просто:

```---
#Deploy playbook

- hosts: myhosts
  tasks:
    - git:
        repo: git@git.example.com:project/repo.git
        dest: /www/mysite
        key_file: /root/.ssh/id_rsa_git
        accept_hostkey: yes
        version: '{{ version }}'

```

Comment: Пардон, разметка съелась

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую попробовать:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    commit_ref: '{{ lookup("env","CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME") }}'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ commit_ref }}'
```

Убедиться, что переменная окружения подхватывается и аналогично использовать в рабочем плейбуке.